# Unable to make Axios retry failed requests

Tags: javascript, axios

*Note: 
Please do not mark as duplicate. I've seen many of the axios posts about attempting retries and I've not been able to get any method, including the built-in interceptors (aware of breaking change v.18->v.19) to work, and I'm still stuck.*

I'm trying to get failed calls to an API to retry due to a race condition scenario where I need the API to be called until it succeeds as it will always succeed eventually but can error if the system created id has already been used.

I created this script to debug what is going on.

```js
const rax = require('retry-axios');
const axios = require('axios').default;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const retryErrorHandler = async (error) => {
  console.log("Running retryErrorHandler");
  const { config } = error;
  if (!config || !config.retry) return Promise.reject(error);

  config.__retryCount = config.__retryCount || 0;
  if (config.__retryCount >= config.retry) {
    console.log("...__retryCount is greater or equal to retry max....final reject");
    // Reject with the error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
  // Increase the retry count
  config.__retryCount += 1;
  // Create new promise to handle exponential backoff
  await sleep(1500);
  const instance = await axios(config);
  instance.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => retryErrorHandler(error));
  return instance;
};


async function makeAxios(){
  console.log('makeAxios');
  const instance = await axios.create();
  console.log('created');
  instance.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => retryErrorHandler(error));
  return instance;
}

async function retryAxios(passedConfig, tries = 0) {
  const maxTries = 10;
  tries = +1;
  console.log(`Retry #${tries} executing a ${passedConfig.method.toUpperCase()} for ${passedConfig.url}`);
  try {
    console.log('before trying to make call');
    console.log({passedConfig});
    const result = await axios(passedConfig);
    console.log({ result });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Retry #${tries} had an error: ${error}`);
    console.log({error});
    if (tries < maxTries) {
      await sleep(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 750);
      console.log(`Total tries: ${tries} is less than the max of ${maxTries}, trying again`);
      axios(passedConfig);
    }
  }
}

async function makeAPICallMethod1(){
  try{
    console.log('started');
    // # METHOD 1 - attaching to global axios with defaults - CLOSEST TO WORKING
    const interceptorId = rax.attach();
    console.log({interceptorId});
    let response = await axios.put('https://httpstat.us/500');
    console.log({response});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Caught an error');
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function makeAPICallMethod2(){
  try{
    console.log('started');
    // # Method 2 - new instance, does not override defaults for retry, retryDelay, or onRetryAttempt
    const axiosInstance = axios.create();
    axiosInstance.defaults.raxConfig = {
      instance: axiosInstance,
      retry: 10,
      retryDelay: 750,
      onRetryAttempt: err => {
        const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
        console.log(`Retry attempt #${cfg.currentRetryAttempt}`);
      }
    };
    const interceptorId = rax.attach(axiosInstance);
    console.log({interceptorId});
    const res = await axiosInstance.put('https://httpstat.us/500');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Caught an error');
    console.log(error);
  }  
}

async function makeAPICallMethod3(){
  try{
    console.log('started');
    // # Method 3 - config can be assigned but doesn't proceed past 1st retry.
    const anotherAxios = await makeAxios();
    let response = await anotherAxios.put('https://httpstat.us/500', null, { retry: 10, retryDelay: 1000 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Caught an error');
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {makeAPICallMethod2, makeAPICallMethod3};


// ===============
// node -p "require('./axios-test').makeAPICallMethod2()"
// node -p "require('./axios-test').makeAPICallMethod3()"
```

Both of these implementations stop after the first execution when they have the retry set to more than that.

Why are the retry attempts not occurring?

For method 2:

```
started { interceptorId: 0 } Promise { <pending> } Caught an error
```

For method 3:

```
started makeAxios Promise { <pending> } created Running retryErrorHandler 
Caught an error Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Comment: Yes I accidentally clicked enter before finishing the post. The code I added runs but does not include the package.json and at the end includes the command needed to run the file.

Comment: What does the output log look like?

Comment: For method 2:
```
started
{ interceptorId: 0 }
Promise { <pending> }
Caught an error
```

For method 3: 
```
started
makeAxios
Promise { <pending> }
created
Running retryErrorHandler
Caught an error
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Comment: I copied the console output into the question for readbility. `makeAxios()` is a synchronous function, you don't need to do an await on it - perhaps that is the source of the error?